# Why not use a ‘block table’ for file systems (in analogy to a page table)?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, filesystems, virtual-memory

File system structure seems similar to memory management structure:

1. Mapping non-contiguous physical frames to contiguous virtual memory
2. Mapping non-contiguous physical disk blocks to contiguous file.

Why not use a ‘block table’ for file systems (in analogy to a page table)?

Comment: Is he reinventing FAT here? :)

Comment: This is what most filesystems do in some form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most filesystems do use some kind of tree-based representation to store their data in. However, there's a lot more state to store in a filesystem tree (such as directory structure, files of different lengths, etc.) than you can store in a page table.

Page tables are designed to allow hardware to:

- easily translate a conceptually flat address space (process memory) to another conceptually flat address space (physical memory)
- quickly understand when to generate page faults for the OS to handle

Any traditional filesystem's internal data structures would be optimized for:

- mapping from the logical concepts of directories and files to a flat address space (blocks on disk)
- decreasing the number of disk reads to do so

Focusing on the performance angle of this, page tables always require exactly log(N) reads (where N is the maximum size of the address space) to get to a page with data in it (ignoring cached values in the translation lookaside buffer). If you were representing a file using a page-table-like structure (which could make sense because that would be a flat address space (file) to flat address space (disk) mapping), if the file was really big and sparse you could store it in a B-tree, which would have fewer levels (log(n), where n is the number of non-empty pages) to traverse before you got the data you were looking for. Each random access to a spinning disk is extremely expensive, so that would be a valuable optimization.